# Onion Skin Texture Stripes

Tags: texturing

Does anyone know how to create this texture/bump? I tried stretching the noise texture but didn't like how it wasn't sourcing from the middle of the object... [image]

Answer (score 3):

You could plug a *Gradient Texture (Radial)* node into your *Noise Texture*, like that:

[image]